# Are there any indications that English is going to split into different languages in the next hundred years?

Tags: dialects, linguistics

Are there any indications that (global) English is going to split into different languages in the next hundred years?

Comment: Closely related: [Do you think American English will keep on deviating from British English or they will one day become the same thanks to globalization?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/do-you-think-american-english-will-keep-on-deviating-from-british-english-or-they). Also, as a general reference: [Where do accents and dialects come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5815/where-do-accents-and-dialects-come-from)

Comment: To properly answer this question we would need working definitions of _split_, _language_, _English_ and _indication_. Some of those are easy enough but I point it out because this isn't a remotely objective question yet. We can theory craft all we want, but to objectively answer this question we need a heck-of-a setup.

Comment: Fascinating question, but both possibly a duplicate and too subjective. But the current answers are somewhat objective so I don't think I'll vote to close.

Comment: @Mitch As you can tell, I have just started to ask questions here, can you tell me if you would have preferred a version that explicitly asks for examples like Tok Pisin below?

Comment: I'm not sure how to reword your question; it's easier to answer well here if objectivity is possible, and questions about the future can lead to both objective and subjective answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If anything, I would expect the opposite to happen.

During the age of colonization many scholars predicted that the distances between English-speaking populations meant that by our times the average American would not be able to understand the average Australian, for example. What happened instead was the telegraph, and the telephone, and other advances in communication that kept far-flung speakers of English in constant contact with each other, thereby reinforcing the commonality of the language. Today, of course, we regularly exchange messages with people living on every continent, thanks to the Internet, which is likely to lead to regional variations either disappearing or being absorbed into worldwide English.

English will continue to evolve, and is likely to pick up qualities from places like India that have not historically contributed significantly to the development of the language before now, but I would not expect to see the English language fragment.

Comment: Although, interestingly, I understand that Dutch is undergoing certain changes (such as simplification of the formal register, and assimilation of the masculine and feminine genders), which Flemish is not. Those languages also benefit from a community which is able to be in constant contact, and which are geographically very close.  Accordingly, I don't think fragmentation is impossible.

Comment: @Marcin: It is said that the Dutch spoken by the majority of Dutchmen and that of most Flemish speakers is diverging, though I am not sure. I, a Dutchman with a standard accent, find it easy to understand the Belgian news, but random people speaking Flemish in an informal setting will be incomprehensible to me for a large part. Then again, the same applies to many Dutch dialects from the Netherlands. It is very difficult to say whether there is general divergence going on, and even more so between which dialects/accents it is strongest.

Comment: @Cerberus: Very interesting!

Comment: I agree. I would add that English has always been quick to coin phrases and adopt words and phrases from other languages, which I think would also make it less likely to split.

Answer (score 4):

My money would be on English becoming more affected by places like India (and perhaps china) for everyday use as another billion english speakers come online.

Traditionally English has been very happy to absorb other language influences so I don't think there will be a formal correct English and a 'street' Indo-English in the way there was latin/vulgate.

Answer (score 3):

Tok Pisin is already a descendant language of English.

In the book "The Last Lingua Franca" there was a fascinating case study of modern Tagalog (Taglish), which mixes in a lot of English, although as with all issues that aren't black and white, one could quibble if it is a form of Tagalog with English loan words, or a English dialect with Tagalog influences.

[http://www.amazon.com/Last-Lingua-Franca-English-Return/dp/0802717713](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0802717713)

Mass media, in my opinion, is really slowing down the rate of language fragmentation compared to what it was historically.

Comment: here's a list of English-based creole languages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-based_creole_languages

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more than just a metaphor to say languages *evolve*.

In that context, I would suggest the Galapagos Islands were a particularly good place for Darwin to investigate the evolution of finches.

Evolution (and more particularly *speciation*) occurs more often and more quickly when there's plenty of scope for populations to become disconnected.

By (more than just) analogy therefore, we can reasonably expect languages in general will become more homogeneous in the future because of increasing worldwide travel and intercommunication.

Logically, we should all be speaking Chinese in 100 years time, but because English has such a dominant position (not just on the Net), I think it will eventually become the only game in town.

I know it's always sad to lose diversity, but most Welsh people took the decision generations ago to bring their children up with English as their primary language. For the quite obvious reason that this would enhance their prospects for economic and cultural / social success.

Comment: similarly Ireland's literary reputation is based on speaking English. If Joyce, Shaw, Wilde had written in Gaelic they would be about as well known as the Icelandic sagas.

Comment: Personally I think we're doing God's own work right here on EL&U by helping to promote our language at this time of flux. Maybe we can get our associates (and alter-egos) over at *programmers.se* to hack into and disrupt *hindi.se* and *chinese.se* if they ever appear!

Comment: No need, for any culture to become sophisticated it has to be able to listen to Radio4, and in order to reach full enlightenment it must play Mornington Crescent - and so must be able to speak English.