# New Yorker Dieresis Rule; prosaic, unionized?

Tags: orthography, diaeresis

There are lots of informal references to the traditional / "New Yorker" style of using diereses to disambiguate runs of vowels, however I have yet to find a definitive guide.

See, for example:

- [New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/culture/2012/04/the-curse-of-the-diaeresis.html)
- [Diaeresis - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic))
- [What is the standard rule for using or not using hyphen and diaeresis on the word? - ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66126/what-is-the-standard-rule-for-using-or-not-using-hyphen-and-diaeresis-on-the-wor)

My major question is: Is there a definitive reference that one can consult for proper traditional use of the dieresis in English? The accepted answer in last link above outlines some cases (e.g., no dieresis in "coalesce" or "react") but notably does not provide a reference to an authoritative source.

My minor questions are:

- Is it appropriate to use a dieresis in "prosaïc?"
- How does one most correctly differentiate the two words spelled "unionized" ("union-ized" about the formation of a group or "un-ionized" about how many free electrons a material has)? Assume for a moment that you have to write both within the same document.

Comment: Major answer: There is no reference that is both traditional and definitive. [Punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf) -- especially odd punctuation -- is simply chaotic in English. Minor answer (1): Yes, but a dieresis, if any, in _prosaic_ would be on the A, not the I -- it would be _prosäic_. Minor answer (2): One makes sure that the topics of ionization and trade unions never come up in the same written sentence, so the contexts will determine. In real language (i.e, speech), there's never any confusion, of course.

Comment: It’s a tad precious. The word has one in French *prosaïque*, but I am not so sure it merits one in English. Then again, consider *mosaïc*.

Comment: @JohnLawler Why would *prosaic* be any different in placement of the diacritic from *naive*?

Comment: Given that you've apparently read Robusto's excellent answer to the other question (http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66144/8019), what exactly do you mean by *authoritative*?

Comment: @JohnLawler: Do you really mean that a diaerisis goes on the first vowel? Without that, your comment would be an excellent answer.

Comment: From the wikipedia source that you cite: "The diaeresis indicates that a vowel should be pronounced apart from the letter that precedes it. For example, in the spelling coöperate, the diaeresis reminds the reader that the word has four syllables co-op-er-ate, not three, coop-er-ate. In British English this usage has been obsolete for many years, and in US English, although it persisted for longer, it is also now considered archaic."

Comment: @TimLymington This is getting kinda meta, but by "authoritative source" I mean something like "a source that wouldn't get scoffed at if cited in an academic paper." (Not that I'm writing a paper, to be clear.) E.g. I'd call the _OED_ and _Strunk and White_ "authoritative" though not (AFAIK) with respect to this question.

Comment: "Why has *naïve* survived, but not *coöperate* ? Why do we write *Noël* but not *poëm* or *reïgnite* ?" The 'i' and the 'a' in  *appreciate* are not a married couple. http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2011/04/diaeresis.html

Comment: Where's the diaeresis in ***diaeresis*** ? And why not? Because it had had to be a triaeresis instead?

Comment: @Kris One no more need write *diæ̈resis* than *diäbetic, dyädic, diöde,* or *quotidiän* — and for the same reason, as well you know.  But if you feel better writing *lysergic acid diëthylamide*, go right ahead. At least that way one can recognize the particular influënces for what they are. The rest of us are content with *un-ionized*.

Comment: I think the only correct way to write the un-ionized meaning is *un-ionized* (well, unless you "think outside the box" and spell it *nonionized*). I don't think a diaresis would help in that case, and you certainly can't run it together, because then it unavoidably becomes the word "union" plus some suffixes.

Comment: @Marthaª Yes, that’s the same approach with which one separates *recreation* from *re-creation*.

Comment: @tchrist All sorts of groups are getting *unionized* these days. I keep off cell-towers to stay *unionized.*

Comment: Going back to the 'authoritative' point: you might like to look at http://english.stackexchange.com/q/93944/8019 and related questions. But for clarity: both I and any academics I know would scoff long and hard at somebody claiming that Strunk and White is 'correct', and the answer to your major question is "No, no more than there is an authority that tells you which words you can or cannot use."

Comment: @Marthaª But why not uniönized (and iönized for that matter) when referring to the molecules?

Comment: @TimLymington Understood about _Strunk and White_, but I hope you get what I was aiming for.

Comment: @danfuzz: that still looks like *union* + suffix to me, just with some stray marks on the paper or screen. (Either that, or someone has a very strange pronunciation of *union*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are lots of informal references to the traditional / "New Yorker" style of using diereses to disambiguate runs of vowels, however I have yet to find a definitive guide.

The definitive guide to the "New Yorker" style, is that you submit a piece to the New Yorker, and if it is accepted for publication it will be cast into that orthography whether you had originally attempted it or not.

The earlier traditional use of diæreses do not have a definitive guide, because it is traditional, and as such was never consistent.

It also isn't really all that traditional, and never dominated English orthography, though it certainly was once more common than before: It was *a* traditional way of writing, not *the* traditional way.

And, to dash your hopes of finding a definitive guide further, it was, and remains, used to different degrees by some than by others.

Today, it would still be very common to use a diæresis with a proper noun, like *Zoë*, *Chloë*, or *Boötes*. Likewise with related proper adjectives.

Overlapping with that, it would be much more common to use it in a foreign loan-word that had the diæresis in the original spelling (likewise its identical cousin the umlaut). This though raises another question; how long is a word in English before it is no longer a loan-word? It also brings up a point about how the language has changed, for not only have loan-words become more and more considered to be fully English, but also writers' sensitivity to the foreignness of loan-words has declined so the average scribe is less likely to choose to italicise in a given case than they would a couple of centuries ago. Of such words, perhaps *naïve* and its relatives (*naïf*, *naïvety*, etc.) may be the only word both widely known as English and widely retaining the diacritic it brought with it from France even though it is now 400 years in English use. Perhaps the very fact that it is learnt of relatively early in a child's developing vocabulary that makes it retain the mark; children learn it as "the one with the dots" just as they learn *fo'c's'le* as "the one with all the apostrophes" and so a general tendency to remove diacritics is resisted just as the general tendency to reduce apostrophes to a ration of one per word.

At the other extreme, those who did (or remain) fond of its use, have no logical reason for avoiding it in *react* and *reaction*, beyond the simple fact that it is so commonly seen without one that even the most given to affected feel slightly silly using it.

In-between, some would use it where there was primary stress on the second vowel, and some more widely.

Similarly, many (relatively speaking) would use it where the word was formed by joining two parts, particularly where another might be tempted to hyphenate.

Many would take how likely they thought mispronunciation would be without it.

There is no doubt some influence too from the lack of such a mark in the Latin source; it coming from Latin already joined rather than combined from *re-* and *act* in English, but that also applies to some words where one does see it: It's an influence perhaps, but not a self-sufficient reason.

> Is it appropriate to use a dieresis in "prosaïc".

It would be technically defensible on the basis of the French *prosaïque*. Some would only use the diæresis when the primary stress is on the second syllable, and so not use it. Some who would tend to use the diæresis anyway still wouldn't as it is so well-known without and not (unlike the also well-known *coöperation* for example) formed from combining two parts.

The New Yorker, incidentally, spells it *prosaic*.

> How does one most correctly differentiate the two words spelled "unionized" ("union-ized" about the formation of a group or "un-ionized" about how many free electrons a material has)?

From context.

> Assume for a moment that you have to write both within the same document.

As a rule even in the same document the two adjectives are unlikely to be applied to very similar subjects or objects, though certainly if workers are finding themselves ionised on a regular basis they definitely need to organise into a trade union.

As such, it's unlikely to cause that much difficulty here.

If though, you really wanted to distinguish them orthographically, then the diæresis is not going to be of any help. Note that the hyphen is allowed, albeit unpopular, in one but not the other. Hence:

> "Organised into a trade union": *unionised/unionized*
>
> "Not ionised": *un-ionised/un-ionized*
>
> "Not made more Ionian": *un-Ionised/un-Ionized* or even *un-Ionicised/un-Ionicized*.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas to this excellent question:

- Contact the *New Yorker* and request their Style Guide. This would be the "definite reference", as least as far as they are concerned.
- [We Resist Further Cooperation on 'Coöperation'](http://www.thewire.com/entertainment/2012/04/we-resist-further-cooperation-cooperation/51631/) indicates that *New Yorker* style editor Hobie Weekes was about to eliminate the dieresis and then passed away. "This was in 1978. No one has had the nerve to raise the subject since."
- Consult the answer already on this stack exchange: [What is the standard rule for using or not using hyphen and diaeresis on the words like reelect , reexamine, and cooperate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66126/what-is-the-standard-rule-for-using-or-not-using-hyphen-and-diaeresis-on-the-wor)

Comment: Great comment. Can't up vote because it's not an answer.